# Xamarin Forms Vertical Options Ignored

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The VerticalOptions="End" in my Xamarin Forms doesn't stick the items to the end of the page (which is what it should do right?), I even tried using an absolute layout with the relative position set to 1, but that didn't move the items to the end either.
Here is my Xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms"
             x:Class="CouchTo5kTracker.HomePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="350"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="AbsoluteLayoutProgress" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView" PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional"/>
                <Label x:Name="WeekCounter" Text="3/5" FontSize="90" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 100, 150, 150" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional"/>
                <Label x:Name="WeekLabel" Text="Week" FontSize="30" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 220, 80, 50" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional"/>
            </AbsoluteLayout>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid x:Name="RunGrid">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3.75*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1.25*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="#1476D2" Padding="10,5,5,5" Margin="8,0,1,5">
                        <Label Text="Next Run" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="15" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="#1476D2" Padding="10,5,5,5" Margin="1,0,8,5">
                        <Label Text="Date" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="15" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="#F7F7F7" Padding="10,5,5,5" Margin="8,0,0,5">
                        <Label x:Name="NextRunLabel" Text="Next Run: Week 4, Run 3" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="15"/>
                    </Frame>
                    <Frame Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="#F7F7F7" Padding="10,5,5,5" Margin="1,0,8,5">
                        <Label x:Name="NextRunDateLabel" Text="12/04" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="15"/>
                    </Frame>
                </Grid>
                <Grid VerticalOptions="End">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Frame Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="End"></Frame>
                    <Frame Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="End"></Frame>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Altering the heirarchy resuts in very unexpected positioning, at the moment I just want to place the two frames at the end of the page. The App is a Xamarin Shell.

Comment: `VerticalOptions` control how an element is placed within it's **parent** container.  In this case, your `Frame` elements are contained within a grid, so `VerticalOptions="End"` will just place them at the bottom of their row.

Comment: Do you know of any way to stick this element at the bottom of the page without resuffling the heirarchy?

Comment: create additional rows on your outermost Grid and place them in the last row

Comment: Thank you that works great if i use Grid.Row="1"